# Reset drop downs to default value after button click

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a grid which is rendered in my template as shown below.  The grid has multiple dropdowns (one per row) and I collect the values of these when I click a button.  However after I click the button I want to reset all the drop downs to the default value.

```
<div>
    <button (click)="onClickUpdate($event, filteredRequesters)">Update</button>
</div>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let requester of filteredRequesters'>
        <td>
          <select id="ddStatus" type="number" (change)="onChange($event.target.value, requester)">
             <option *ngFor="let level of levels">
    {{level.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>{{ requester.RequesterID }}</td>
        <td> {{ requester.FullName }} </td>
        <td>{{ requester.CompanyName }}</td>
        <td>{{ requester.RequesterClass}}</td>
        <td>{{ requester.Address}}</td>
        <td>{{ requester.MobilePhone}}</td>
        <td>{{ requester.TotalRequests}}</td>
        <td>{{ requester.EmailAddress}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the array that sets the options in the select drop down in the typescript component.

```
   levels: Array<{ num: number, name: string, total: number }> = [
    { num: 0, name: "ignore", total: 0 },
    { num: 1, name: "child", total: 0 },
    { num: 2, name: "parent", total: 0 }
   ];
```

And finally here is code for the button click:

```
 onClickUpdate(event, filteredRequesters) {

    var count: number;
    count = 0;

    for (var i = filteredRequesters.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (count > 1) {
            continue;
        }

        if (filteredRequesters[i].isDisabled == 2)
            count++
    }

    if (count == 1) {
        this._productService.updateRequester(filteredRequesters);
        var countToRemove: number;
        // get new total requests for merged reqwester  
        var countIndex: number = 0;
        countToRemove = 0;
        for (var i = filteredRequesters.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (filteredRequesters[i].isDisabled == 1) {
                countToRemove += filteredRequesters[i].TotalRequests;
            }
            else if (filteredRequesters[i].isDisabled == 2)
                countIndex = i;

        filteredRequesters[countIndex].TotalRequests += countToRemove;
        filteredRequesters[countIndex].isDisabled = 0;

        for (var i = filteredRequesters.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (filteredRequesters[i].isDisabled == 1)
                filteredRequesters.splice(i, 1);
                // this._productService.getRequestersByFirsterLetter('a')
                // .subscribe(products => {
                //     this.products = products;
                //     this.filteredRequesters = this.products;
                // },
                // error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
    else alert("Only one parent allowed. ")       
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is not working?

Comment: NP -  - after I click the update button. Any selects which have been changed by the user do not reset back to the initial option.  I need all the selects to reset back to the initial option, but i don't know how to do this in typescript. Thanks

Comment: easiest way, make it a form and just call `form.reset()` when you want. If that is a possibility, to make it a form that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wish to add form, then at least you can add ngModel to the select element to bind it value to a property and then reset it. Then you don't need to retreive (change), it's bound. Something like the following:

```
 <select id="ddStatus"  [(ngModel)]="selectedValues[i]" type="number">
```

where `selectedValues` is that property. Then you easily reset its values:

```
 reset(){
      this.selectedValues=["ignore","ignore","ignore"];
  }
```

call `this.reset()` from the button click method.

simplified [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trfho7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)